# How to make my android application UN-SHARABLE?

Tags: android

I developed an android application for my organization. 
How can I make it UN-sharable, so that the application can't be SHARED via ANY application (such as apps like MyAppSharer etc.) or ANY means whatsoever?

I want to implement this as a security mechanism so that the application cannot be distributed without my organization's permission.

Update: Mainly intended to make the app unshareable through apps like ShareIt

Answer (score 1):

You mean pirated? If you're going to put your app on Google Play, Amazon, or any other store, in the end someone will figure out how to pirate it. No matter how hard you use ProGuard.

If you're developing an App for **internal** use inside your company, just connect to one of your internal servers and check it's there every time the app is open. For a normal user emulating your "10.0.1.10", or "192.168.1.2" server it's going to be difficult